# Django show me an incorrect date due to time zone

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, utc

I have a model in django that stores datetime fields:

```
class Trip(models.Model):
    departureDate=models.DateTimeField()
    arrivalDate=models.DateTimeField()
    duration=models.IntegerField() #in seconds
    price=models.FloatField()
```

I have introduced this datetime: 2021-05-18 12:29:00+02:00 2021-05-18 13:19:00+02:00.
When I show it in the view, I see hour and minute 11:19.

I have this in settings:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I need to show hour and minute 13:19, but I don`t want to put UTC=False.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two `DateTime` fields, you need to show the correct field.

And if you need to convert time to a different timezone you can use `datetime.astimezone()` method with `pytz` object.

Comment: It doesn`t matter the field. It happens with both.

Comment: Is it compulsory to convert the DateTimeField to time zone 0 to get my objective ?

Comment: Firstly your question is not so much clear, you said you introduced two times above. one is `2021-05-18 12:29:00+02:00` and the other is `2021-05-18 13:19:00+02:00`. So ideally the first should show `12:29` and the other `13:19`. If it does not do that then you might have set the time incorrectly. I would recommend you to review you code logic or edit you question and provide more details along with necessary code.

Comment: Converting timezone is up to you, i just mentioned that. For example if your display timezone is same as your projects's setting timezone then you dont need to convert and vice versa.